# Detect if an open file/device has been replaced/deleted

Tags: linux, filesystems, monitoring, udev, usbserial

Assume the following situation under Linux:

A process is continuously reading from an USB-serial converter device (`/dev/ttyUSB0`). That device is **suddenly unplugged** and plugged in again (or is resetting itself for some reason). The process continues to have a valid file handle for `/dev/ttyUSB0` but won't receive any data from the device unless the process re-opens the device (because *udev* has deleted and re-created the device node).

Is there a *direct* way to detect such a situation (ie. **not** indirectly by detecting a timeout in data flow) so that the process knows it has to re-open the device? Would it be reliable to monitor the modification time of `/dev/ttyUSB0` using `stat()`?

Additional details:

The process opens the device file by using the standard `open()` function.

`/dev` is a `tmpfs` controlled by `udev`.

**Note:** I do *not* want to use any *udev* rules for this and prefer a solution implemented directly in the process.

Comment: [inotify](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a USB device is hot-unplugged, operations on the device will begin failing with `-EIO`; you can detect this and take appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks, that's right, I'm getting that error after unplugging. Can I safely assume that the file descriptor has become useless when getting EIO or are there situations that cause a **temporary** EIO and where the file descriptor becomes functional later? Currently I have implemented a logic that completely closes, re-opens and re-initializes the device (a modem) after a read() with EIO.

Comment: @Udo: It's _possible_ - for example, if your hard disk is having some kind of transient mechanical error, you might get an -EIO on one read, the hard disk recovers, and the next read succeeds. However it's unlikely, and reinitializing the device is probably the right thing to do if you see an -EIO.

Answer (score 1):

If the device node is actually being removed and re-created (which I believe it is if you have udev), then you should be able to use the inode number to tell when this happens.

Just call `fstat()` on your open file descriptor, `stat()` on `/dev/ttyUSB0`, and compare the `st_ino` fields of the two `struct stat`s.

And let me know if it actually works.  :-)

Comment: The strategy works for me. I implemented it in python: https://github.com/hrchu/python-scsi/blob/b4e796bd92c4af9501ac597eda87840db4c0f0e5/pyscsi/pyscsi/scsi_device.py#L106

Comment: Update: inode of device file does not change for certain device types. In my box, device file of usb mass storage devices always have the same inode even after replugged.

Answer (score 0):

I think `FAM` or `gamin` will detect these events.